# How to fetch the Data return from the map in Java script

Tags: javascript, mongodb

The below code is returning a map object , is there any way to get the data from that ?
i tried with `'Object.values ( mapData)'` , but it is not displaying me any thing

Code is :

```
    async function fetchDatafromDB (client, IDs)
{
  for (var i=0; i<IDs.length; i++) {
    console.log ('the value is ' + IDs [i]);

    const cursor =client.db ('snapp_transactions').collection ('price_check_validation').find ({
      Scenario: {
        $in: [
          IDs[i]
        ]
      }

    });
    let mapData =new Map ();
    while (await cursor.hasNext ())
    {
   
      const obj = (JSON.stringify (await cursor.next ()));
      console.log (obj.replace (/\\|\//g, '')) ;
      
      var dataArray = obj.substring (10, obj.length - 2).split (',');
     

      for (var k=0 ; k <dataArray.length ; k++) {
        var split_value = dataArray[k].replace (/['"]+/g, '').replace (':', '=').replace (/\\|\//g, '');

        console .log ('split_value is ' + split_value) ;

        if (split_value.length === 1) {
          mapData.set (split_value[0].trim (), '');
          
        } else if (split_value.length === 2) {

          mapData.set (split_value[0].trim (), split_value[1].trim ());
        
        } else {  }
      }

     
    }
```

I have tried with get() it is giving me ' undefined '

Comment: You can use the [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) methods, e.g. `keys` or `get`

Comment: mapData.get () is giving me  'undefined '

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. What is `cursor`?

Comment: i have given the complete code.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [MDN - Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

There are methods:

1. clear
2. delete
3. **entries**
4. **forEach**
5. **get**
6. **has**
7. **keys**
8. set
9. **values**

Answer (score 0):

### You can use for...of loop to get more access to map object:

```
    const mapData = new Map();
    
    mapData.set('a', 1);
    mapData.set('b', 2);
    mapData.set('c', 3);
    
    for (const iter of mapData) {
      // We can iterate and get each item at a time
      console.log(iter);
    }
       
    // Get keys and values from Map
    
    keys = [];
    values = [];
    
    for (const [key, value] of mapData) {
      keys.push(key);
      values.push(value);
    }
    
    console.log(keys, values);
```

[Click here to run the code for your self](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-emraao?file=index.js)